# Passing parent 'vm' object to custom directive instead of method(&) and model(=) bindings angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Can some one please help me understand this?

I have a custom directive included in a controller and I want to use the same directive across multiple pages.The directive template contains buttons and their corresponding actions will be handled in the controller the directive is included in.

```
Controller
------------------------------------------------------------------------
angular
    .module('test')
    .component('approval', {
      template: '<data-table scopeObj ="vm"></data-table>',
      controller: 'PendingApprovalsController',
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
    .controller('approvalController', approvalController);

  approvalController.$inject = ['$scope'];
  /* @ngInject */
  function approvalController($scope) {

    var vm = this;


    vm.search1 = function(val) {
       console.log("search1::", val);
     };

     vm.search2 = function(val) {
       console.log("search2::", val);
     };
    vm.search3 = function(val) {
       console.log("search3::", val);
     };
    vm.search4 = function(val) {
       console.log("search4::", val);
     };
    vm.search5 = function(val) {
       console.log("search5::", val);
     };

  }

Directive
---------------------------------------------------------------------
angular.module('test')
    .directive('dataTable', dataTable)
    .controller('dataTableController', dataTableController);

function dataTable( ) {
    return {
      scope: {
        scopeObj: '='
      },
      controller: 'dataTableController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      template: '<button class="btn-default" ng-click="scopeObj.search1('search1')">Button1</button> <button class="btn-default" ng-click="scopeObj.search2('search2')">Button2</button>+
        <button class="btn-default" ng-click="scopeObj.search3('search3')">Button3</button><button class="btn-default" ng-click="scopeObj.search4('search4')">Button4</button>'
    };
  }


  dataTableController.$inject = ['$scope'];
  function dataTableController($scope) {

    var vm = this;

  }
```

1.Can I make directives scope as false and reuse the diretive across mulptiple pages?

2.Can I pass controllers 'VM' object to the directive instead of passing individual methods like

```
<data-table method1="vm.search1(val)" method2="vm.search2(val)" method3 ="vm.search3(val)" method4="vm.search1(val)"></data-table>
```

and accessing them inside directive

scope: {
    method1: '&',method2: '&',method3: '&',method4: '&'
  }

as I got too many methods to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is definitely something you can do, but you'll need to make the following changes in order for this to work:

- Don't use `dataTable` as your directive name. `data` is not allowed as a directive name since AngularJS will strip `data` from every directive it finds. `data` is a reserved keyword when working with attributes. Try `statTable` instead.
- Use `<` to bind `scopeObj` as you only need one-way binding for this problem.
- Set `bindToController` equal to `true` in `statTable` so that we can reach `scopeObj`'s methods using the `controllerAs` syntax.
- In your template, make sure you use `scope-obj` as the attribute name. Remember, the attribute is referred to in camelCase in the scope, but is in kebab-case in templates (similar to defining directives).
- In the `statTable` template, call `vm.scopeObj.method()` as opposed to `scopeObj.method()` directly, since your `scopeObj` is a property of `vm` (since we are using `controllerAs` syntax here).

Put it all together, and you'll get the effect you desire. Check out the code below with the proposed changes:

```
angular.module('test', [])
  .directive('statTable', statTable)
  .controller('statTableController', statTableController)
  .directive('testDirective', testDirective)
  .controller('testDirectiveController', testDirectiveController);

function statTable() {
    return {
    scope: {
        scopeObj: "<"
    },
    bindToController: true,
    controller: "statTableController",
    controllerAs: "vm",
    template: "<button class='btn-default' ng-click='vm.scopeObj.search1(\"search1\")'>Button1</button> <button class=\"btn-default\" ng-click=\"vm.scopeObj.search2('search2')\">Button2</button> <button class=\"btn-default\" ng-click=\"vm.scopeObj.search3('search3')\">Button3</button>"
  };
}

function statTableController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.log = console.log;
}

function testDirective() {
    return {
    controller: "testDirectiveController",
    controllerAs: "vm",
    template: "<stat-table scope-obj='::vm'></stat-table>"
  }
}

function testDirectiveController() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.search1 = function(val) {
        console.log("search1::", val);
  };

  vm.search2 = function(val) {
    console.log("search2::", val);
  };

  vm.search3 = function(val) {
    console.log("search3::", val);
  };
}
```

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gmn2drer/) for a working JSFiddle. Clicking on the buttons produces the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions Christian.Couple of questions, 1.Will there be any performance hit if we pass "vm" object to directive instead of method bindings. 2. Instead of passing "vm' object to directive, can I used scope:false inside directive so that I'll have access to parent scope and still reuse the directive in multiple pages? Thanks..

Comment: For the maximum performance gain, use a **one-time binding** by adding `::` when setting `scope-obj` in the `testDirective`'s template (I updated answer and JSFiddle with this change). This setup will have no impact on performance as it does not set up unnecessary watchers. As for setting `scope` to `false`, you *can* do this, but it is not recommended as we want to stick to Angular 2+'s component architecture whenever we can to make upgrading easier (there is no scope inheritance in Angular 2+). It would also be a good idea to set `statTable` up as a `component` as opposed to a `directive`.